# How do I update Cart Options using Codeigniter 2x Cart Library?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I search through documents provided by Codeigniter for updating cart options value, but it only mention updating Cart value not option value.

I tried to update something like this.

```
foreach ($this->input->post() as $key => $value) {
    $data = array(
        'rowid' => $key,
        'options' => array('color' => 'red', 'size' => 'xl')
    );

    $this->cart->update($data);
}
```

But didn't work out. I googled it but none of them worked for me. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to supply a quantity?

Comment: yes, here I've just listen option only.